# waiting for data from server then execute a function, async and sync code in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await

i have a problem when waiting for data from the server, i want to wait till the variable myData gets data then execute the return statement so the components gets the new data updated inside checkMyData, i get null on console.log("new data", someData).

UPDATED THE CODE

```
//service methods
getBooks():any{
 const myData = null;
 this.httpClient.get(url).subscribe(
  data=>myData = data,
  error=>myData = error
 );
 return checkMyData(mydata); 
}  

checkMyData(someData){
 //some code here
 //maybe modifying someData
 return someData;
}

//components methods

const booksList;
getBooksFromService(){
 this.service.getBooks().subscribe(
    data => booksList = data,
    error => booksList = error
 );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `map` on the `Observable` that you're getting inside the `getBooks` method:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class BookService {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getBooks(): any {
    let myData = null;
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    return this.httpClient.get(url)
      .pipe(
        map((res: any[]) => this.checkMyData(res))
      );
  }

  checkMyData(someData: any[]) {
    //some code here
    console.log('In Check My Data: ', someData);
    //maybe modifying someData
    someData = someData.map(book => book.name);
    return someData;
  }

}
```

And then you can call it in your Component like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BookService } from './book.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private bookService: BookService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.bookService.getBooks()
      .subscribe(books => console.log('Got the books as : ', books));
  }  
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/return-from-service-when-either-got-success-or-error?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: it works, thanks for your time, that is what i wanted